# matlab gui uiwait hide the new figure behind the current one

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have two figures. In figure 1 m file, I write 
run figure 2.m
uiwait(figure1);

Then in figure 2, after some process, I write 
uiresume(figure1)

The thing is that after matlab run figure 2, the figure flashes and hide behind figure 1. I need to move figure 1 and then operate on figure 2 which is very inconvenient. Can anyone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`figure`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html). Here's an example:

```
h1 = figure; %// create figure 1
plot(1:5, 'o');
h2 = figure; %// create figure 2
plot(ones(1,5), '*');
```

Now the first figure is behind the second. To bring the first figure forward (make it the current figure), use

```
figure(h1)
```